# AJAX GET command to to get states o the lights

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to do a html application to run in a localhost tha allow to control phillips hue lights. I'm adapting EVOThings base code to do it. Now I need to do a function to know the states of each bulb to refresh it on HMI, but I'm not confortable with AJAX code.
If I do a GET command in the API, I get this response,
[Example of a GET response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5Wtz.png)

```
{
    "1": {
        "state": {
            "on": true,
            "bri": 172,
            "hue": 0,
            "sat": 0,
            "effect": "none",
            "xy": [
                0.3124,
                0.3301
            ],
            "ct": 0,
            "alert": "select",
            "colormode": "xy",
            "mode": "homeautomation",
            "reachable": false
        },
        "swupdate": {
            "state": "notupdatable",
            "lastinstall": null
        },
        "type": "Extended color light",
        "name": "Hue color lamp 1",
        "modelid": "LCT015",
        "manufacturername": "Philips",
        "productname": "Hue color lamp",
        "capabilities": {
            "certified": true,
            "control": {
                "mindimlevel": 1000,
                "maxlumen": 806,
                "colorgamuttype": "other",
                "ct": {
                    "min": 0,
                    "max": 65535
                }
            },
            "streaming": {
                "renderer": false,
                "proxy": false
            }
        },
        "config": {
            "archetype": "sultanbulb",
            "function": "mixed",
            "direction": "omnidirectional"
        },
        "uniqueid": "00:17:88:01:04:57:b0:ac-0b",
        "swversion": "1.29.0_r21169",
        "swconfigid": "3416C2DD",
        "productid": "Philips-LCT015-1-A19ECLv5"
    },
```

and I have a AJAX PUT function to change the bulbs state,

```
 app.lightSetState = function(lightId, state)
 {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://' + app.getHueBridgeIpAddress() +'/api/' +
            app.user + '/lights/' + lightId + '/state',
        data: JSON.stringify(state),
        success: function(data) { },
        error: function(a, err) { }
    });
 };


 //turn device on
 app.lightOn = function()
 {
    app.lightSetState(app.lightId, {"on":true});
 };


 //turn device off
 app.lightOff = function()
 {
    app.lightSetState(app.lightId, {"on":false});
 };
```

now I think that the solution will be somthing like this,

```
 app.lightGetState = function(lightId, state)
 {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://' + app.getHueBridgeIpAddress() +'/api/' +
            app.user + '/lights/' + lightId,
        data: .............  ,
        success: ............ ,
        error: 
    });
 };
```

Can someone help me?
I'm open to any suggestion to do this state refresh.

Best Regards :)

Comment: Can you clarify your question?    You said you want to get the state but the fourth line of your first block of code shows the state as 'on'

Comment: Hi @LTPCGO, When I do GET the lights the API give me that information that I post. As I said i want to "capture" if "state: on" is true or false and I don't know how to do it. the goal is change the bulb icon if the light is on or off and keep my app sync with bulbs everytime. The main issue is that I'm not confortable with AJAX. 
thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: You need to actually be comfortable with JSON but I will post an answer :)

Comment: What code produces the first block of code you show?

Comment: the last piece of code does nothing... was a kind of example that what could be the solution... but if i do  'http://' + app.getHueBridgeIpAddress() +'/api/' +
            app.user + '/lights/' + lightId
i get what you see in the link on the main post... thanks for your cooperation..

Comment: Therein lies your solution.  I updated my answer.

Comment: I'll try it and then I answer you. One more time thanks for your time :)

Comment: I accidentally left an `alert` in the final code which I've removed now, make sure you use the latest version

Comment: In the last version you mixed two diferent functions. will be better to show you my entire code. I sent it to your email (enquiries). thanks again for your help.

Comment: Can't answer e-mails for SO answers, it's not useful for the wider community, + is for enquiries regarding questions that require an in-depth, multi-day, bespoke solution which fairly compensates my time...unless you want to initiate a contract for this work!

That said...the answer doesn't mix functions, I use one function (`JSON.parse`) to make sense of the data returned by the `getState` function.  I then pass the answer to `app.lightGetState` which I assume is a publicly accessible variable in your `app` class.  Whether it is or isn't, answer is in that variable after `=`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks anyway. acctually i have 2 functions: app.lightGetState(lightId) the one who does the AJAX GET dependent of the lightId and getstate() function that I create to pass the result of the app.lightGetState(lightId) to a text box. it is just a debug function.

Answer (score 0):

You state you get the JSON response through a call to the URL, so:

```
function getState(app, lightId)
{
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://' + app.getHueBridgeIpAddress() +'/api/' + app.user + '/lights/' + lightId,
        success: function(data) {
            return data;
        },
        error: function(a, err) {}
    });
};

var jsontext = JSON.parse(getState(app,lightId));
app.lightGetState = jsontext[1].state.on;
```

In reality you really shouldn't use `async: false` because it's depreceated.  You should remove the `return` methods and do your procesing in that `success:` function.

As an explanation:
The data you showed in your GET example is JSON, so you need to parse that into an object that I've called jsontext.  The tricky bit is that the key is '1', but once we have that (`jsontext[1]`) we get the `state` key, and then the `on` key, which will return `'true'` or `'false'`, and you can use those strings in your later code

Comment: my comment was too log so i post an answer.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried to fit this on my code:

function getstate(){
  var estado = app.lightGetState(2);
  document.getElementById("textbox8").value =  estado;

}


and the result in the textbox8 was "undefined". Did I miss something?

Best regards and thanks for your cooperation.